# How to find route between 2 points like Google Maps does

Tags: google-maps, flutter

How can I find the shortest distance between 2 coordinates, just like Google Maps.

Comment: You only need to know how to extract a list of `LatLng`?

Comment: yes I already have start and end and know how to draw polylines but cannot find anything on how to get the directions to go from start to end

Comment: you can use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator to get the actual lat ang long

Comment: yes I have LatLng but I need all the middle points to construct a route like in actual google maps

Comment: You will have to press `+` icon at the top right corner of the screen to see the line. Do let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: it does work but it's not what I asked I aldready drew polylines I need the directions of actual streets to create a route and to do so I need points between start and end

Comment: @GiorgioOlivero Can you show the screenshot of what you are looking for?

Comment: https://askdavetaylor.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/google-maps-send-directions-phone-9.png like this but i don't have the points between start and destination to draw the car/walk/bike ride

Comment: Please use `@` when referring me, else I don't get notification from SO, now, what I got from you is you want to build the shortest route between 2 points which are your starting and ending lat lng?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Basically yes that's what I'm missing

Comment: For that you will have to use paid service from Google Maps, it is called Google Maps Direction API. You can't do it on your own effectively.